# Configure the Activities within the Social Pane to default "In Progress"

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-365

I have this requirement:

> The ask here is to modify the Activities View to combine the "Overdue" and "In Progress" Activities into one view and make it the default.  This should be the default approach for the all Activities views.
>   [image]

From my initial investigation, I don't believe this is doable within Dynamics.

If I'm correct, would I be able to add a web resource and write some JS to manipulate the dropdown to default to the "In progress" option? Is this is a best practice? Should I just say this is not something we can do?

Any guidance/resources is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately Social pane customizations are very limited at this point of time. The functionality you are expecting is not possible to implement by OOB configuration/customization, we can try to do some unsupported solutioning but eventually it will break in future updates.

Instead of timeline/social pane, may be you can develop a custom HTML webresource to fetch the activities & display in same manner with whatever flexibility you want.

Comment: I appreciate the guidance, Arun. Thanks for the info!